# Different definition of fibre bundle

Tags: general-topology

I have 2 definition of fibre bundles, one from the book Fibre bundles from Husemoller and the other one from The topology of fibre bundles by Steenrod. And they differ.

The first definition says that if $(X,p,B)$ is a principal G-bundle (that is, "a bundle" of the form $(X,pr, X \mod G)$, where $G$ has **free** action on $X$ and $pr$ is canonical projection), F is a right G-space (that is, $F$ has free right action of G)
then fibre bundle is triple $(X \times F \mod G, p_{F}, B)$, where $G$ has action on $X \times F$ of the form $(x,y)s=(xs,s^{-1}y)$, and $p_{F}$ is factorization of projection to the first coordinate composed with $p$.

The second definiton first introduces coordinate bundle that contains the general "bundle" $(X,p,B)$ with fibre $Y$ and with group $G$ having **effective** action on $Y$. The definition requires local triviality $\phi_{j}:V_{j}\times Y \to p^{-1}(V_{j})$, where $V_{j}$ is covering of $B$. And requires coordinate transformations between $\phi_{i},\phi_{j}$ on common space $V_{i}\cap V_{j}$ coincides with the operation of an element $g \in G$ (meaning I guess that it's a map $y \mapsto g \times y$ on $Y$ for some $g$)
Fibre bundle can be then understood as being maximal with respect to the amount of coordinate transformation functions (roughly speaking...)

My question is, how much do these definitions differ? Is the first definition more strict when we consider locally trivial fibre bundles? Also why does one of them need free action and the other one effective action?

Comment: Husemoller's fibre bundle is the fibre bundle associated to a principal bundle. The definition of Steendrod is different, but both bundles are ismorphic. I recommend you chapter 6 of Jeffrey Lee's book (not John Lee, be careful) and Kobayashi Nomizu's fisrt book, the final section of chapter 1.